# Passing Arguments to Hex on Windows Command Line

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments

I want to pass arguments manually on the Windows command line consisting of hex values of the byte e.g. "\x41\x42\x43\x44"  - a sequence of 4 bytes on the cmd.exe command line to a program.

How do I do this? Cannot seem to find an escape sequence for using byte values in hex.

Comment: The expected format of the arguments is up to the specific program they're being passed to, it's not just something you can do in general.  If your program _is_ expecting this format, what's happening when you try to use it?   Which escape sequences have you tried already (`^\`, `\\`?)?

Comment: I am writing a command line based Buffer Overflow which requires me to send hex bytes which cannot be typed e.g. 0x00 etc. There should be a generic way of doing this

Answer (score 3):

I'm not fully sure what it is you're trying to accomplish, and you have avoided requests for clarification, so I'll try and answer it as it stands, in a general way:

You can't do what you're trying to do.

Command-line parameters are (always) of a string/character type, and it's up to the program they're being fed into to define the expected format and type of the accepted argument.